# ImageMagick refused to convert the animated GIF and killed the process silently due to CPU

Tags: linux, conversion, imagemagick, gif

I tried with these solutions below, but unsuccessfully:

- [ImageMagick convert problem, command killed or silently exits](https://askubuntu.com/questions/576717/imagemagick-convert-problem-command-killed-or-silently-exits)
- [Using disk for processing of huge images](https://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?t=33434)
- [ImageMagick convert out of memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48423113/imagemagick-convert-out-of-memory)
- [ImageMagick using more than 2GB of memory to convert PDF files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15384879/imagemagick-using-more-than-2gb-of-memory-to-convert-pdf-files)

My animated GIF has 13.5MB. My computer has 16GB RAM memory. I have 8 CPUs of AMD Ryzen 7 2700X. I received the error:

```
$ convert -limit memory 2MB -limit map 2MB -limit area 1000MB -delay 2 -loop 0 "Bug do pagamento.gif" Extraídos/bug.png
convert: unable to write pixel cache '/tmp/magick-RSymnnZRmXzueDXGI3ehEtIiUkBcymGa': Sem espaço livre no dispositivo @ error/cache.c/WritePixelCachePixels/5830.
convert: corrupt image `Bug do pagamento.gif' @ error/gif.c/DecodeImage/505.
convert: corrupt image `Bug do pagamento.gif' @ error/gif.c/ReadGIFImage/1368.
convert: no images defined `Extraídos/bug.png' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3285.
zsh: exit 1     convert -limit memory 2MB -limit map 2MB -limit area 1000MB -delay 2 -loop 0 
convert -limit memory 2MB -limit map 2MB -limit area 1000MB -delay 2 -loop 0   2,75s user 2,73s system 99% cpu 5,505 total
```

Using `LANG=C`:

```
$ LANG=C convert -limit memory 2MB -limit map 2MB -limit area 1000MB -delay 2 -loop 0 "Bug do pagamento.gif" Extraídos/bug.png
convert: unable to write pixel cache '/tmp/magick-RlftdgBD6MZCwArQzkuz5QI-kJtui7yk': No space left on device @ error/cache.c/WritePixelCachePixels/5830.
convert: corrupt image `Bug do pagamento.gif' @ error/gif.c/DecodeImage/505.
convert: corrupt image `Bug do pagamento.gif' @ error/gif.c/ReadGIFImage/1368.
convert: no images defined `Extraídos/bug.png' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3285.
zsh: exit 1     LANG=C convert -limit memory 2MB -limit map 2MB -limit area 1000MB -delay 2  
LANG=C convert -limit memory 2MB -limit map 2MB -limit area 1000MB -delay 2    2,84s user 2,60s system 99% cpu 5,454 total
```

- `tmpfs`:

```
LANG=C df -h /tmp
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
tmpfs           7,9G  7,2M  7,9G   1% /tmp
```

Comment: Can you run the same command this way `LANG=C convert ... the rest of your options`? Also it might be worth trying doing the same using `ffmpeg`.

Comment: Updated. The same error.

Comment: Your command fails probably because: `No space left on device in /tmp`. You might have run out of space in `/tmp`.

Comment: No, only less than 6% of my SSD is occupied. The `/tmp` is not a partition.

Comment: In modern Linux distros `/tmp` is often `tmpfs` which occupies exactly half of your RAM. Please show your `df -h /tmp` output.

Comment: Updated. Check my question detail.

Comment: Could you try with `-limit memory 4GB` ?

Comment: The same error. :-/

Comment: Please try asking here as well: https://github.com/ImageMagick/ImageMagick/discussions or maybe even open an issue: https://github.com/ImageMagick/ImageMagick/issues

Answer (score 0):

I finally moved to `ffmpeg` who does the job.
This is the command I used to convert from a 24M video to a 2.8M gif.

```bash
ffmpeg -i <input_file>.mp4 -r 15 -vf scale=512:-1 out.gif
```